# Keeping authentication related data when moving from the HttpURLConnection to the HttpsURLConnection

Tags: security, sharepoint, java-8, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

So,

I've got here Java SE 8 application.

**Platform**: IntelliJ, and Mac OS.

I authenticate with the `Microsoft SharePoint` Web application on its home page by using `NTLM` auth schema. I do that by using Core Java networking API. I tried other libraries, such as from Apache, but somehow authentication succeeds only with Core Java methods.

Alright, here it comes auth code, which works:

```
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

    final String authHost = "http://domainSample.com/one/two";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                     clientAuth.getUserAdmin() , clientAuth.getPassword().toCharArray());
            }
        });

        URL URLAuth = new URL(authHost);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) URLAuth.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.connect();
```

The headers on the `conn` object on response:

```
{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], SPIisLatency=[0], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.5], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Persistent-Auth=[true], Last-Modified=[Tue, 27 Jun 2017 16:37:41 GMT], X-FRAME-OPTIONS=[SAMEORIGIN], request-id=[74c9ff9d-4d14-0038-1c59-424a812a2885], Date=[Tue, 27 Jun 2017 16:37:40 GMT], MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=[15.0.0.4911], X-MS-InvokeApp=[1; RequireReadOnly], SPRequestGuid=[74c9ff9d-4d14-0038-1c59-424a812a2885], Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], SPRequestDuration=[94], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Expires=[Mon, 12 Jun 2017 16:37:41 GMT], Content-Length=[161234], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], X-SharePointHealthScore=[0], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]}
```

Now the above code authenticated the app, the client, with the remote system. Now I want to communicate with the REST type service on the same system, in order to get response on service request.

The URL becomes this:

```
 final String urlService = "https://domainSample.com/api/birds/getAllBirds";
```

The relevant code is here:

```
URL URLService = new URL(urlService);
            HttpsURLConnection conns = (HttpsURLConnection)URLService.openConnection();
            conns.setDoOutput(true);
            conns.setDoInput(true);

            conns.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conns.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
 conns.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            conns.connect();
```

Obviously, I get in response the:

```
HTTP 401 : Unauthorized
```

Because I am on a new connection object, which is now **HTTPS** based.

The system uses custom security certificate, which I added on the keystore on the JRE before.

So, I want to keep the authentication data and transfer it on the HttpsURLConnection object. So that I perform authentication at the very beginning of the process, and then continue with multiple calls on the actual service system.

Now, when you look at the headers, which come in response to successful authentication (HTTP 200), I see there nothing useful which I could reuse for such use-case. E.g., I even don't receive a `Cookie`.

I tried the `URLConnection` instead of the `HttpURLConnection` object upon authentication, yet no Cookie comes in.
I would use Cookie's relevent key-value pairs to identify myself as already authenticated and pass it on with each subsequent request.

When it comes to headers in response, they've got something called:

- request-id
- SPRequestGuid

which look like unique identifiers, which did no good passing them in with the subsequent request.

So,

what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that any session initiated over http simply cannot be transferred to https.  The server can see that the new connection is https and may simply refuse to associate it with an existing session token identified with http.  In fact, this would likely be considered a security flaw if it did.  Https sessions generally would require that the connection is encrypted first, before any authentication is completed, so that authentication details cannot be intercepted.  In others words, authentication over https can only be initiated after the connection is created, for it to be secure.

Regarding your questions about session tracking, typically sessions are tracked with session ids.  Session ids are tracked with either cookies or http headers, and in fact you might have to actually add the session id to any further connection from the same machine (either as part of the URL for a GET request or as part of the headers for POST).  If you do not, you are probably creating a new session for every single http request.  If you do manage to resend the session id correctly, it can be invalidated by the server if the server sees a request with the same id coming from a different browser or different ip address.

Even if you manage to maintain a session across multiple requests in your code, you probably cannot transfer that session to https, for the reasons stated above, I suspect no web server would allow it.